# Adding items to .git/info/exclude doesn't ignore them

Tags: git

I have a file in my directory, `myproject.sublime-project`. When I add it to the exclude file, such that the file looks like

```
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~
myproject.sublime-project
```

, the file is still not ignored; doing `git status` shows it as an untracked file. However, adding it to `.gitignore` does work, it no longer shows up as untracked.

Is there a way for me to get `.git/info/exclude` to behave the same as `.gitignore`?

Comment: And what happens if you use git push ? Are the files you wanted to be ignored ignored ?

Comment: Git push does nothing, since the files are not committed or added to the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that seems to work:

Add the files into the `.gitignore` and use `$ git  update-index --assume-unchanged .gitignore` to prevent the changes to the `.gitignore` from being commited.